# API call and Navigation controls with SurveyJS

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

I am using SurveyJS (https://surveyjs.io/) to make a simple site with few questions. I am able to do all my logic with the options provided by SurveyJS.

However, what I'm looking to do is:

- Make an API call after one of the question *(working as expected)*
- Wait for the API call before moving to the next question *(working as expected)*
- **If the API responds `false`, do NOT move to the next question. *(not working)***

No matter what I do, the survey continues to move to next question and I want to avoid that in this case.

Three callbacks that are available:

```
// triggers before the current page goes away
survey.onCurrentPageChanging.add(function (sender, options) {
    if(survey.data.year === "1991") {
        // let's say I want to stop user from going forward at this point.
        // how can I do that?
    }
});


// triggers after the current page is gone and new page is about to appear
survey.onCurrentPageChanged.add(function (sender) {

});


// triggers right before the survey is about to finish - the last page
survey.onCompleting.add(function (sender, options) {

});
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Whoever is going to downvote, please explain yourself. Do you even understand the question or know what SurveyJS is?

Comment: I am not a downvoter, but you need to show your code if you want some help.

Comment: There is not much to show with SurveyJS but I will update with 3 callbacks that the library provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
survey.onCurrentPageChanging.add(function (sender, options) {
    if(survey.data.year === "1991") {
        // This prevents survey go to the next page
        options.allowChanging = false;
    }
});
```