# getting question and option by api call only in survey.js

Tags: javascript, survey, surveyjs

I am using `SurveyJS`, but I'm new to this document.

In survey.js you need to provide json of both option and question once before starting survey.

But my requirement is to **do api call for each question when user clicks on next button**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you can iterate through the all questions using the following code:

```
var json = { /* survey JSON */ };
var survey = new Survey.Model(json);
survey.getAllQuestions().forEach(function(question) {
    // work with question here
    // question.<property name>
});
```

Comment: thanks for the support but another solution helped me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588462/api-call-and-navigation-controls-with-surveyjs